How to pass a struct (e.g. struct A) that contains a std::promise<A> between threads by using std::promise and std::future?
Actually,the struct A contains a std::funtion toExecute,std::any result and std::promise<A> p.
I want to set "result" to the return value of "toExecute" and then pass this struct back to main thread by using "p".
Error:
error: static assertion failed: template argument must be a complete class or an unbounded array

Code to reproduce:
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

struct test{
    std::promise<test> p;
    int val;
};

void setVal(test &t){
    t.val = 1;
    t.p.set_value(t);
}

int main(){
    test t;
    std::promise<test> p;
    std::future<test> f = p.get_future();
    t.p = std::move(p);
    std::thread t1(setVal, std::ref(t));
    t1.join();
    std::cout << f.get().val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


You can't declare an std::promise with an incomplete type. Not only that though, t.p.set_value(t); can't work either because test can't be copied (only moved) due to the promise inside of it, but you can't use t as both l- and r-value in the same expression either.

I guess you are looking for std::promise<std::reference_wrapper<test>>?

Thanks,I'll try it and please wait for my reply

"struct test{
std::promise p;
int val;
};" that looks like a bad plan.  Why does a chicken contain a promise of a chicken, are you laying eggs?

maybe......so I give up this
